# Error ng new projectName

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have updated me angular version to 4, but since i have a probelm to create new project with angular/cli, i know that the problem is a bout a packag.json file in my home directory how must be deleted but i cannot know how to find it.

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 7.6.0
os: linux x64
@angular/animations: 4.0.1
@angular/common: 4.0.1
@angular/compiler: 4.0.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.0.1
@angular/core: 4.0.1
@angular/forms: 4.0.1
@angular/http: 4.0.1
@angular/platform-browser: 4.0.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.1
@angular/platform-server: 4.0.1
@angular/router: 4.0.1
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
```

in the terminal:

```
 ng new test4
 You cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI project.
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You mean `.angular-cli.json` ?

Comment: It is the file(.angular-cli.json) that i must delete? and where i can found it? thanks

Comment: It's a hidden file, so you won't see it in your folder. `Ctrl+H` in your folder if you're on Linux or https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files on windows to display hidden files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error, i have a package.json
file in my home directory, when I delete this file everything working well

thanks

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you should run "ng new" in a parent directory, neither in a directory where you want the new project to be nor in a directory where there is already some project.

For example if you want to create a new project in /home/user/projects/hello, then you should go to /home/user/projects and run "ng new hello".

If you already had a working project, just upgraded the Angular to 4.0.1 and CLI to 1.0.0, then you need to follow the upgrade instructions https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli - removing node_modules and running "npm install" which will fetch new packages. No need to run "ng new" again.